# Getting an error while importing products on Magento from my other store

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, product, import, import-products

I am having an issue while importing products. Keep getting an error that my csv file is invalid. Can anyone help? I downloaded this file from my other Magento Store. I have also made sure all the categories match. Attached is a screenshot of error.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the errors and accounting for the headers in the .CSV file, the *attribute set* names listed on rows `2, 5, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, etc.` are not present in the target Magento instance (or do not match completely).

You'll need to create all *attributes* and *attribute sets* **exactly** how they are currently in the other Magento instance.

It has also determined that the *category* listed in rows (again accounting for the .CSV header first row) `3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, etc.` are also not present in the target Magento instance (or do not match completely).

You'll need to also create all *categories* **exactly** how they are currently in the other Magento instance, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your attribute set 
check if the ids of attribute set are the same as your other store

Comment: I added all my attributes from the other store but still getting errors

Comment: should have the same ids

Comment: You mean the same attribute code?